# Set test environment in Django

Tags: python, django, path

I've been testing the `manage.py` script of django. My problem is that my tests always run against the production or general configuration `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` instead of my local test directory, for example: `/home/<user>/Code/django/django-dev/django/`. Any idea to set this?

This is my sys.path:

```
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/alucard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

I tried to run the script with the `PYTHONPATH` set as `/home/<user>/Code/django/django-dev/django/`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Nope. Could it help me with this? I'm on linux anyway.

Comment: There's nothing too linux specific about virtualenv, but whenever you need more than one environment on the same machine virtualenv is your friend (and it's easy to use too).

Comment: You should really always be using a virtualenv for your development projects.

Comment: remember, no virtualenv no party.